# How can I draw text that looks embossed using Kinetic JS and canvas?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs, kineticjs

**Update** - Here is my final [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chadsaun/x77tjrw6/) working version using Kinetic.

I'm trying to show text with two different shadows to create an "embossed" look.  I'm using this [jsfiddle as a model](https://jsfiddle.net/chadsaun/s59154qa/3/) of the result I'd like to get which uses CSS.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chadsaun/x77tjrw6/1/) of what I'm working on currently with Kinetic JS.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'stage-container',
  width: 400,
  height: 200
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var darkShadow = new Kinetic.Text({
        text: 'Hello',
    x: 140,
    y: 80,
    fill: '#000000',
    fontSize: 60,
    opacity: 0.8,
    filter: Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
    filterRadius: 1
});                         

layer.add(darkShadow);

var lightShadow = new Kinetic.Text({
        text: 'Hello',
    x: 136,
    y: 76,
    fill: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 60,
    opacity: 0.3,
    filter: Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
    filterRadius: 1
});                         

layer.add(lightShadow);

var mainText = new Kinetic.Text({
        text: 'Hello',
    x: 138,
    y: 78,
    fill: '#FFFFFF',
    fontSize: 60,
    opacity: 0.8
});                         

layer.add(mainText);

layer.draw();
```

I am currently drawing the text 3 times and just offsetting them to get each shadow and then the main text.  My issue is that the main text needs to have opacity to bring forth the background color.  Here are a few screenshots to see what I'm up against.

Just the shadows...

[image: Just the shadows]

With all 3 text objects...

[image: With all 3 text objects]

My next thought was to create a clipping mask of the main text to subtract that out of the two shadows, then draw the main text with opacity to bring forth the background color.  But I'm not exactly sure how to do that or if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Compositing

#### Use "destination-out" to remove pixels.

If I knew how to use kineticjs I would say just set the layer composite operation for the last text layer to "destination-out" and that will remove the pixels.

But too much work to sift their documentation so here is the same thing without any frameworks.

```js
// constants
const text = "Compositing";
const blur = 2;
const highLight = "rgba(100,190,256,0.75)";
const shadow = "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)";
const font = "84px arial black";
const background = "linear-gradient(to right,  #1e5799 0%,#3096e5 100%)";
const border = "2px solid #6CF"

// create canvas add styles and put on page
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const w = (canvas.width = innerWidth - 24) / 2;  // set size and get centers
const h = (canvas.height = innerHeight - 24) / 2;
canvas.style.background = background;
canvas.style.border = border;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// set up font and font rendering alignment
ctx.font = font;            
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

// draw dark shadow
ctx.shadowBlur = blur; // shadow
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = shadow;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = ctx.shadowOffsetX = blur;
ctx.fillText(text, w, h);

// draw highLight
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = highLight;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = ctx.shadowOffsetX = -blur;
ctx.fillText(text,  w, h);

// draw center text that removes pixels
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";               // turn off shadow
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; // New pixels will remove old pixels making them transparent
ctx.fillText(text,  w, h);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";     // restore default composite operation.
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you!  I've implemented this into Kinetic and got it working.  One problem though, is that I've got a slight "halo" effect going on.  Can you see what might be the cause of that? http://jsfiddle.net/chadsaun/x77tjrw6/13/

Comment: @Chad That is the light shadow blur extending over the dark shadow. The is not much you can do to fix it without changing the intensity/contrast of the effect that will have to be compensated for in the shadow & text colours. Move the highlight text up and left by one pixel, or the highlight shadow offset by the same. Or use more layers and reduce the shadow blur, offsetting the text with lower Alpha that creates the blur via repetition. There are many ways to create the embossing effect, experiment and see what suits you.