# How can I draw a text with Concavity

Tags: node.js, canvas

I am currently playing around with canvas and trying to achieve a text effect like this (the black blurry inner shadow/Effect with Concavity):

[image]

But I cannot find a way to create text with concavity. I wonder whether it is still possible? The text color should be the same as background image.

There should have a three-dimensional effect.

It should be similar with this one.

[How can I draw text that looks embossed using Kinetic JS and canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242709/how-can-i-draw-text-that-looks-embossed-using-kinetic-js-and-canvas)
@Blindman67

Here is the sample code from @Blindman67 and I change it a bit, but the inner shadow effect looks not good.

```
const text = "ABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVW";
const blur = -5;
const highLight = "rgba(205,129,98,0.85)";
const shadow = "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)";
const font = "normal bold 70px sans-serif";
const background = "url('https://www.instyle.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Elmobaltique_43003_1280x700-0.jpg')";

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const w = (canvas.width = innerWidth - 24) / 2;  // set size and get centers
const h = (canvas.height = innerHeight - 24) / 2;
canvas.style.background = background;
//canvas.style.border = border;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// set up font and font rendering alignment
ctx.font = font;
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    // draw dark shadow
    ctx.shadowBlur = blur; // shadow
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = shadow;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY =  blur;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = blur;
    ctx.fillText(text, w, h);
    ctx.fillText(text, w, h + 0.5);
    ctx.fillText(text, w + 0.5, h);

    // draw highLight

    ctx.fillStyle = highLight;
    ctx.shadowColor = highLight;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
    ctx.fillText(text,  w, h);
    ctx.fillText(text, w, h + 0.5);
    ctx.fillText(text, w + 0.5, h);


    // draw center text that removes pixels
    ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";               // turn off shadow
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; // New pixels will remove old pixels making them transparent
    ctx.fillText(text,  w, h);
    ctx.fillText(text, w, h + 0.5);
    ctx.fillText(text, w + 0.5, h);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inset-shadow on HTML5 canvas image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378088/inset-shadow-on-html5-canvas-image)

Comment: thanks. I have tried this, but its not mine.. it should be similar with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242709/how-can-i-draw-text-that-looks-embossed-using-kinetic-js-and-canvas

Comment: It's the same the source is text or image. Both links would work.